# zipsplit -F (error: Invalid command arguments)

Tags: compression, zip

I'm passing the F flag to zipsplit to try to fix a zip file however I get the following warning:

```
zipsplit -F photos_test.zip
zipsplit error: Invalid command arguments (Use option -h for help.)
```

What's wrong ? Do I simply not have such parameter in my zipsplit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`zipsplit(1)` man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/zipsplit.1.html):

```
SYNOPSIS  
   zipsplit [-t] [-i] [-p] [-s] [-n size] [-r room] [-b path] [-h] [-v] [-L] zipfile
```

So, no.

Comment: ok. So, is there no option to fix compressed zip files ?

Comment: Not in `zipsplit`. `zip` has one though.